# Button won't appear for admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The button just won't appear for the admin account.

Migration code:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :fname,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :lname,              null: false, default: ""
      t.boolean :admin,             default: false
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
      ...
```

Model code:

```
def admin? 
  self.admin == true 
end
```

This is code for the view:

```
<% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
    <%= link_to 'New category', new_category_path %>
<% end %>
```

I set the admin from rails console like this:

```
a = User.find(1)
=> #<User id: 1, fname: "", lname: "", admin: false, email: "bobonnaaa@gmail.com", created_at: "2017-05-10 21:29:29", updated_at: "2017-  05-10 22:08:28">
a.admin = true
=> true
a
=> #<User id: 1, fname: "", lname: "", admin: true, email: "bobonnaaa@gmail.com", created_at: "2017-05-10 21:29:29", updated_at: "2017-05-10 22:08:28">
```

Did I do something wrong? Please help.....thanks!!

Comment: you don't even need `admin?` method, just use `current_user.admin?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you save the record in the console? You have to call `a.save` after assigning `a.admin = true` with the way you are assigning currently.

Comment: Worked!! Thanks a bunch

Comment: Also, the  fname and lname fields are empty strings in the rails console, hence they are not showing in the browser. Pls what do I do?

Comment: You can assign to them the same way you assigned to the admin attribute.
```a.fname = 'Bob'
a.lname = 'Smith'
a.save
```
You can also assign all attributes at once and save them with
```User.create(fname: 'Bob', lname: 'Smith', admin: true, email: 'bob@smith.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your console,

```
User.find(1).update_attribute(:admin, true) #you haven't save your user after assigning true to admin
```

then you don't need `admin?` method as it is a boolean datatype, you can directly use like,

```
<% if current_user.try(:admin) %>
  <%= link_to 'New category', new_category_path %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I now get the scope

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't define the `admin?` method. It already exists.

Then you need to persist the update on your record so run `User.find(1).update(admin: true)`

and in the view:

```
<% if current_user&.admin %>
  <%= link_to 'New category', new_category_path %>
<% end %>
```